# OpenSSL s_client returns unsupported certificate purpose on one machine but works normally on another with same certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm debugging TLS connection issue between host and docker container. My docker container has a server certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This certificate is issued by CA with following certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When i run `s_client` on **host** machine:

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile ./ca.crt -connect localhost:7051 -servername insurance-peer
```

It returns

```
 SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 94B93D75B297584B53E87ADA0968F2B3B9121F1CAA048212642195E299F6BEA24E482E19E35F5FF18D596E138955EEBF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1571897582
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 26 (unsupported certificate purpose)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Note that the return code is `26 (unsupported certificate purpose)`

When I run `s_client` on **docker** container

```
$ openssl s_client -connect insurance-peer:7051 -CAfile ./ca.crt
```

It returns:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:85B6CAD935415FFDCC76623E9A1B5FC1749D3B7B450B41316F581A181D29039CA092B55F25170ED8D125B7ACFBE33289
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1571897694
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Note that return code here is `0 (ok)`

So in case of `s_client` connection between host and container the error is `unsupported certificate purpose` while in case of connection within the container it works normally.

`$ openssl verify` works ok in both environments.

**Host:**

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ./ca.crt server.crt
server.crt: OK
```

**Docker:**

```
# openssl verify -CAfile ./ca.crt server.crt
server.crt: OK
```

OpenSSL version on **host** machine: `OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019`

OpenSSL version on **docker**: `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Can you please assist me what can be the issue here?

Comment: Looks similar to this bug report: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1760#comment:5 . Your CA key reports "Any Extended Key Usage". It is supported since OpenSSL 1.1.0. This is why different versions behave differently. To fix, I feel, you need to update OpenSSL.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yeah looks like it. It is reproduced with `openssl verify -CAfile ./ca.crt -purpose sslclient ./server.crt`. Many thanks. Would you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to this bug report: [Nginx #1760](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1760#comment:5).

Your CA key reports "Any Extended Key Usage". It is supported since OpenSSL 1.1.0. This is why different versions behave differently. To fix, I feel, you need to update OpenSSL.